# all pandas rows end up with same values after zip list, why?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue and I am 2000% sure it's me being a bit silly

df1 coordinates is a zip list of lat and long values. The problem is, when I try and define it, every rows coordinates column ends up with the same value in tac_grouped.

Can anyone help me with why?

```
df1 = df[['magnet.tac','magnet.latitude', 'magnet.longitude']].copy()
df1.columns = ['TAC','Lat','Long']
df1['coordinates'] = list(zip(df1.Lat, df1.Long))
tac_grouped = df1.groupby('TAC')['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: list(zip(df1.Lat, df1.Long)))
tac_grouped= pd.DataFrame(tac_grouped).reset_index()
```

Comment: Because every apply zips `df1.Lat` and `df1.Long`. Do you mean `x.Lat` and `x.Long`?

Comment: @Alollz Good eye! (why singular?)  Good eyes!

Comment: It's refreshing to hear "I have an issue and I am 2000% sure it's me being a bit silly" rather than "I'm doing everything right and Python is broken".

Comment: Ahh OK - so when I change that I get the below error. Sorry, I am not really experienced with lambda functions, so if it's a stupid question, I apologise: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Lat'

Comment: @MadPhysicist LOL  So true.

Comment: Not sure why are are zipping.  Well in general not what you trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: `apply` passes a single row to the lambda, no? Please provide sample output and inputs

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all tuples of (Lat, Long) within each group? I think you could do `df1.groupby('TAC').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.Lat, x.Long)))` (probably a better way)